# Editable Google Spreadsheet on Google site - assign username

Tags: google-sheets, google-classic-sites

So here is what I am trying to do:

Have a Google site that has an embedded *editable* Google Spreadsheet on that allows end users (if they have been given permission) to edit the spreadsheet.

Here is the purpose, I am trying to create a tasks list application that allows authorised users to view a list of currently available tasks (from Google Spreadsheet) and then assign themselves a task (which will be one of the columns in the spreadsheet "assigned". Is there a way to have that column (assigned) a drop down box of the current user signed in? I.e. so when user 1 logs in to the site, any task they want to assign themselves will have a drop down option of blank or their name.  The same goes for all other users.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

The following piece of code does the trick.

### Code

```
function onOpen() {
  // get active spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // create menu
  var menu = [
    {name: "Add active user", functionName: "addUser"}
  ];

  // add to menu
  ss.addMenu("Add user", menu);
}

function addUser() {
  // get active spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // get first sheet
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  // get data
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getUserLoginId()

  // get active/selected row
  var activeRow = ss.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();

  // set user to cell
  sheet.getRange("B"+activeRow).setValue(user);  
}
```

### Explained

It adds a menu item to the existing menu upon file opening. The selection lets the user decide whether to assign her/his name (e-mail). I've tried it, using my own two accounts in two different browsers.

### Example

See example file I've created: **[add active user](https://docs.google.com/a/jacobjantuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AluAYY6ZHeWYdHNQVmRYT25ORXZmU3Nmd2pSME1rLVE#gid=0)**

Answer (score 0):

When you link the spreadsheet, it comes up with a link at the bottom to open the document.  Or when you upload it, you can upload it as a list which is editable.